# How to replace all occurrences of a sequence starting with a given string to the next appearance of a symbol?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I would like to edit a huge single line file with thousands of occurrences of some string `'string_string':` until the next appearance of a comma `,` (including this comma) and removing those occurrences from the file.

I assume that either `sed` or `awk` can be used to do that. They are advertised as tools to manipulate strings/character streams but also to be more applicable for multiline files.

Since both `awk` and `sed` commands can be some kind of cryptic and I would like to learn while solving daily occurrences of different problems I would like you to give a brief explanation of the resulting command itself.

My first approach was to let `vim` run a recorded sequence but this is running for 3h now and not even close to the end - even if it would at some point in time solve the problem I would like to know a better and more efficient way.

Requested example:

```
['string_string': <asdffds.1j2_3>, 'abd_dfA': 212, 'kajaj': <asdffdsa>, 'string_string': <fdjjdjd.asjsk2222>, 'jsjsjsj': 32.23], 
['string_string': <asdffds.1j2_3>, 'abd_dfA': 212, 'kajaj': <asdffdsa>, 'string_string': <fdjjdjd.asjsk2222>, 'jsjsjsj': 32.23]
```

Result:

```
[ 'abd_dfA': 212, 'kajaj': <asdffdsa>,  'jsjsjsj': 32.23], 
[ 'abd_dfA': 212, 'kajaj': <asdffdsa>,  'jsjsjsj': 32.23]
```

Comment: Well, I see. Just for completeness: Is there any chance that the `string_string` entry is the last element of such an `[ ... ]` array? In that case it would not have the "next `,`" as delimiting character.

Comment: @AdminBee good question - but can't happen. Probably something the example lacks... (leaves room for improvement). Maybe I should have put a comma even there so the question doesn't arise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `sed` can handle lines longer than LINE_MAX (which is as low as 1024 bytes on some systems), you could do:

```
sed "s/'string_string':[^,]*,//g" < your-file
```

If not, you can always use `perl` instead:

```
perl -pe "s/'string_string':.*?,//g" < your-file
```

Comment: or awk: `awk "{gsub(/'string_string':[^,]*,/,null)}1"`, just for completeness.

Answer (score 1):

One way , using string processing to monitor the positions of string_string & comma , one after the other. In each pair:

```bsh
perl -plse '
  substr($_,$p-1,$q-$p+1,"")
           while
  ++($p=index($_,$s,$q-$p)) &&
  ++($q=index($_,",",$p));
' -- -s="'string_string':" file
```